# Recording video and uploading online in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have got a new requirement to record a video from mobile phone and it should be uploaded on sharepoint online.

Is there anything directly in SharePoint or can we create a custom page to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upload it in **Stream** and share it with your users in your organization.
Go to App launcher Menu and select **Stream**.

[image]

Comment: where can I find stream ?

Comment: But this is not giving any option to record video directly from phone

Comment: No this app it aims to upload videos and share it with users but there is no app in SharePoint online record video directly from phone.